# No Output When Using tail -f With Multiple Grep Commands In Mac OS-X

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I'm trying to execute the following command from the Mac OS X terminal:

```
$tail -f FILE_PATH | grep "DESIRED_STRING" | grep -v "EXCLUDED_STRING"
```

Unfortunately I do not get any results in return.

But, when using `cat` instead of `tail -f`:

```
$cat FILE_PATH | grep "DESIRED_STRING" | grep -v "EXCLUDED_STRING"
```

I get the expected result. Unfortunately, this workaround is no good for me, as I need to tail the file in realtime.

Comment: Have you tried adding `--line-buffered` to your `grep`s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`grep` buffers its output by default. Since `tail -f` never completes, neither does `grep` and you must wait until the last one has accumulated enough output to fill its buffer. With `cat`, the command eventually completes, allowing both `grep`s to complete and print whatever output they have accumulated (whether or not its buffer was filled).

Adding `--line-buffered` to the `grep` commands changes how `grep` buffers its output, allowing you to see the output as each line is complete.

Comment: tail -f POSTMORTEM_FILE_PATH | grep **--line-buffered** "DESIRED_STRING" | grep **--line-buffered** -v "EXCLUDED_STRING" Works as expected!